# I have no idea how to input images into SVR sklearn, convert to numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to do Support Vector Regression using images on x column and value (float) on y column.

Through error code `'could not convert string to float: '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Test1/DATA/SATURATION/0deg_LED_saturation/87/20220510_130313.png'`I assumed that SVR sklearn only allowed numerical (float, i think?) and since my data is a image directory (which is a string), it wont work.

```
    Filepath    Turbidity
0   /content/gdrive/MyDrive/Test1/DATA/SATURATION/...   75.45
...
770 /content/gdrive/MyDrive/Test1/DATA/SATURATION/...   114.70
```

Then i read somewhere that you need to use label encoder in order to convert those string into float, but it appears that label encoding would fit best if the data is categorical, for example `'Japan, US, China, India, China'`, then it would be converted to `'0, 1, 2, 3, 2'` and it wont be able to read the images data (i think?), thus i dont think this is the solution.

I'm thinking about converting them into array separately using `images_ndarray = np.asarray(images).astype('float32')` but there's an error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Any comment, especially advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/image-classification-using-machine-learning-support-vector-machine-svm-dc7a0ec92e01

Check this article. It has explanation on how to use SVR for classification

Comment: It was SVC, for classification. By the way, I have followed it before for the input step, but when I tried to fit the X column, it has this error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`. And I don't think the tutorial works for me because it has only 3 categories, while mine has 154.